# Delphi | Calling a procedure that has the parameter's (Sender: TObject);

Tags: delphi, events, calculator, procedure

I want to link a key to an edit by the procedure, like, I press `0` on the number pad and the procedure `TForm.button0Click(Sender : TObject)` is called, but I don't know how to do it.

```
procedure TForm1.buttonNum0Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edit1.Text := edit1.Text + '0';
end;`

procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  case key of
    '0':
      buttonNum0();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `buttonNum0Click(Sender)`

Comment: As Andreas already mentioned either pass on the ``Sender`` parameter or, if you don't use it anyways, pass on ``nil``.

Comment: Surely you call the click method rather than the event handler

Comment: `buttonNum0.Click;`

Answer (score 0):

You can't map an event handler to a specific key that's pressed. There are only OnKeyPress and OnKeyDown events where you'd need to examine the key that was pressed and then call another method for each specific key. But at that point, there's no need for it to be structured like an event handler with a Sender parameter. If it's a method only for processing something specific to one keypress, eg, '0', then it just needs to be named that:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  case key of
    '0': ProcessKeyPress_0;
    '1': . . .;
    . . .
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ProcessKeyPress_0;
begin
  edit1.Text := edit1.Text + '0';
end;
```

It's a lot more applicable when you use shifts and controls and direction keys. This is a well-known way of doing special actions when certain key combinations are pressed.